# Is tilde '~' normal before dollar '$' sign in terminal prompt?

Tags: command-line, prompt

Is '~' normal before the $ sign, like, `robert@robert:~$`? I do not remember seeing it before.

Comment: It's telling you your $PWD, or *present working directory*.  The "~" is shorthand for your $HOME, or `/home/$USER` or your user directory.

Comment: FYI:  My prior comment contains some likewise shorthand.  As I don't know your username, I couldn't use it in my comment so used $HOME (type `echo $HOME` to see what it will be), likewise `echo $USER` will display just your username, which was the other way I expressed the same detail (getting around what I didn't know).

Comment: I have redacted "*I am having some trouble moving around in the folders and files and downloading a program*" from your post. Since, it's a different question, consider asking a new question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Absolutely. The `~` is saying that you're in your home directory. When you navigate to other directories, the `~` will change to reflect the path you're in.

Examples of what I see with my machine:

| Location | What I See |
| --- | --- |
| Home Directory | `jason@carbon:~$` |
| Apache Root | `jason@carbon:/var/www$` |
| Downloads | `jason@carbon:~/Downloads$` |

Answer (score 0):

The tilde `~` just means "your home directory", which in path language would be `/home/youruser`.

The `robert@robert:~$` text is the prompt of the command line. It's just informative of who you are and which path you are in, so you don't have to worry as it's not part of a program execution. Basically:

```
user@hostname:path$
```

---

You can retrieve the same information with some commands:

```sh
$ echo $HOME
/home/youruser

$ echo $USER
youruser

$ cat /etc/hostname
yourhostname
```

---

The dollar sign `$` at the end means that you are a regular user, not the administrator. When you are logged in as administrator it changes to a hashtag `#`:

```
admin@hostname:~#
```

---

The tilde `~` then, is a special character used by the shell (bash) in some contexts to be *expanded* to your user home path.

---

The prompt can be changed to whatever you feel like, editing the `.bashrc` file.